# Setting static IP address to run installation on OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, dns, localhost, static-ip-address

I'm trying to run an installation (for a software called Prohits to manage mass spectrometry data) on my localhost server.

One of the requirements is that it occurs over a static IP address. So I set up a static IP address using directions [here](http://slinkware.com/help/configure-static-ip/) and verified that it worked by navigating to other webpages. However, the installation is still not able to run and still shows the following error:

> WebAddress: 127.0.0.1
>   Use the server static IP address to run the installation. If this computer has dynamic IP address, it can only run the Lite version`

I don't know if I'm interpreting the error incorrectly or am missing something. The instructions for network configuration state 'Set a fixed IP address and DNS address for the server' which I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installation should not be run using the 127.0.0.1 address; it should be run using the same static IP address as the address that is set for the network. So if the static IP address is set to something like 192.45.134.52, then the localhost server should also be running on that same address.

To implement this change, open up the `hosts` file at `/etc/hosts` and change your localhost server's IP address to the static IP address you set (in this example, 192.45.134.52).